# Fresh Magento 1.9.1 install shows wrong price format in dropdown menus of configurable products

Tags: configurable-product, price, ce-1.9.1.0, dropdown-attribute

Every other place where the price is shown it is done in the correct **1.234,00** € (dot for thousands, comma for decimal) format except for dropdown menus of configurable products where the incorrect format of **1,234.00** € is shown. The language is set to German and sole selected currency is Euro. I have no idea what could be causing it. Is this a bug in version 1.9.1?

Answer (score 0):

I have no solution but will share my observations. This is the line that determines price formatting in the options:

> [Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable::getJsonConfig()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/4bc632edf76c1008b7dccde3e5c7357ce2c00087/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Configurable.php#L252)
>
> ```
> str_replace('%s', '#{price}', $store->getCurrentCurrency()->getOutputFormat()),
> ```

`getCurrentCurrency()` uses the `Mage_Directory` model and `Mage::app()->getLocale()`, so I don't see where this should go wrong. But I hope this helps to debug the issue.